# How to pass a non static method from a specific class as parameter to Function

Tags: java, methods, parameters

This would be the equivalent in C++, all dought i'd like to pass non static functions and only methods of Foo:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  double method1 ()
  {
    return 1.0;
  }
  unsigned char method2 ()
  {
    return 2;
  }
};

template <typename T> 
T myMethod (T (*methodFromFoo) (void))
{
  return methodFromFoo ();
}
```

The return type of myMethod has to be generic, because i want wrap methods of different return types.
What would be the syntax in java 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is different based on the type of method.  You need to read up on `Lambda's, Method references, and Functional Interfaces` in Java.

In your example, a supplier would work.

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class PassingMethods {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     PassingMethods pm= new PassingMethods();
     Foo foo = new Foo();
     pm.getVal(foo::method1);
     pm.getVal(foo::method2);
    }
    
    
    public <T> void getVal(Supplier<T> sup) {
        System.out.println(sup.get());
    }
    static class Foo
    {
    
      double method1 ()
      {
        return 1.0;
      }
      char method2 ()
      {
        return 'a';
      }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
1.0
a
```

I changed the char return to return an 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

This is handled in java by functional interfaces.  Since your methods take no arguments, and return a value, the equivalent java syntax is [`Supplier<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html).

So, the resulting method would be:

```java
public <T> static T myMethod(final Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return supplier.get();
}
```

And to invoke it by passing in the appropriate `Supplier<T>`.
For example:

```java
public void invokeWithInlineLambda() {
    final int result = myMethod(() -> 10); // result = 10
}

public void invokeFromMethod() {
    final String result = myMethod(this::getResult); // result = "Meow"
}


private String getResult() {
    return "Meow";
}
```